# react native {textAlign: 'justify'} fake space after text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a problem, a space appear from nowhere below one of my text

[image]

`listInformations` is an array of string.

I have check, there is no space after the last word of this paragraph.

I have add green `backgroundColor` to show you.

```js
listInformations.map((item: any, index: any) => {
    return (
        <View style={{ marginVertical: 2 }} key={index.toString()}>
            <Text style={{textAlign: 'justify', backgroundColor:"green"}}>{item}</Text>
        </View>
    );
})
```

Comment: it maybe related to the text itself.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that the corresponding text value of the listInformations array ends with "minime.", no other speicial character such as "\n".

Comment: there is nothing after last work, even special character

Comment: please try to add `white-space` style to the Text.

Answer (score 2):

You can try trimming the text.

```js
listInformations.map((item: any, index: any) => {
    return (
        <View style={{ marginVertical: 2 }} key={index.toString()}>
            <Text style={{textAlign: 'justify', backgroundColor:"green"}}>{item?.trim()}</Text>
        </View>
    );
})
```

Comment: I already try, this doesn't work because there is nothing after last word